# cypress.io waiting for same alias

Tags: cypress

```
cy.server();
cy.route('POST', 'my/api').as('myApi');
...
cy.wait('@myApi');
...
cy.route('POST', 'my/api').as('myApi');
cy.wait('@myApi');
```

When my app calls the same API twice within the same test, from the above code, the 2nd `cy.wait` finishes immediately since it sees that the first API is already finished. To get around this, I append a random number behind all my route aliases. Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do better. The cy.route() command is just a definition, so you should group all your routes at the top of the file. Routes only need to be defined once. Then try chaining your waits, as in `cy.wait().otherStuff().wait()` or at least chaining your waits with other stuff that has to succeed first.

Comment: How would it work if I have to `wait` for the same route twice? Does the `wait` know? To me it seems like the 2nd `wait` returns immediately if it's the same alias as the first one.

Comment: Cypress commands are async, so they can return immediately without resolving. A command has to resolve before other commands in the chain are run. That's why I suggested chaining to get the behaviour you want. Cypress also manages retries, so cypress will wait until an assertion becomes true before continuing with the next command in the chain. This is a good way of pacing your tests. Calling wait with a duration is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the question! I think the previous answer is totally right. By default, cypress routing is just aliasing. You could find a similar example in the cypress documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Waiting).

So, you code should be something like that:

```js
cy.server();
cy.route('POST', 'my/api').as('myApi');
cy.wait('@myApi').then(() => {
    // You probably want to add some assertions here
});

// Do your stuff here

cy.wait('@myApi').then(() => {
    // Second assertion. Probably, something should be changed in the second request.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, for the second wait, you can try the following.

```js
    cy.server();
    cy.route('POST', 'my/api').as('myApi');
    cy.wait('@myApi').then(() => {
        // You probably want to add some assertions here
    }); 

        // Do your stuff here

    cy.wait(['@myApi', '@myApi']).then(() => {
        // Second assertion. Probably, something should be changed in the second request.
    });
```